# Indirect Concavity

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $g(x_1,x_2) = e^{\min{(x_1,x_2)}}$ at each $ x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Find whether or not $g$ is indirect concave on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have thoughts on the problem and can share what you have tried? It help responders to understand where you are. Regards